# Only want one item to be returned in get route

Tags: node.js, express

Im trying to make a get route that will only return the names of recipes but im getting all the info in the array instead. Is there some thing im missing?

```
const express = require('express');
const { recipes } = require('./data/data.json');


const app = express();


function filterByQuery(query, recipesArray) {
    let filterResults = recipesArray;
    if (query.name) {
        filterResults = filterResults.filter(recipes => recipes.name === query.name);
    }
    return filterResults;
};

app.get('/recipes', (req, res) => {
    let results = recipes;
    if (req.query) {
      results = filterByQuery(req.query, results);
    }
    res.json(results);
});


app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port 3000!`);
});
```

Comment: The question title doesn't seem to fit with the code.  `filterByQuery()` is filtering the results to only recipes that have a matching name.  So, if you returned only names, you'd have an array of identical names, not particularly useful.  What exactly do you want the result of your `/recipes` route to be?

Comment: My goal is the have the just the names of the recipes returned in a new array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My goal is the have the just the names of the recipes returned in a new array.

First off, it appears from your other code that the `recipes` variable is an array of recipe objects which has properties such as `.name`.  If so, you would get all the names of all the recipes by doing this:

```
app.get('/recipes', (req, res) => {
    const names = recipes.map(recipe => recipe.name);
    res.json(names);
});
```

It's unclear why you were trying to call `filterByQuery()` because it is programmed to return whole recipes that match a specific name.  That's a completely different function than getting just the names of all the recipes.

In addition, to get all recipes, you don't need to use `req.query` as there is no query parameter involved in getting all recipes.

Comment: Thank you for your help, sorry i wasnt clear with my question. YOur answer helped me a lot and it was what i was looking for. Do you know of any site that have good examples of GET and POST routes? I'm having truoble finding some.

Comment: @Scott2n - There are tens of thousands of questions here on stackoverflow using the Express library which all show various types of route definitions, including GET and POST.  There are also thousands of articles on the web about how to code with Express where the most common activity in Express programming is defining route handlers for GET and POST requests.  Your question here didn't actually have anything to do with Express.  This was just array manipulation to get just one property out of an array of objects.

Comment: @Scott2n - Since it looks like you may be new here, if this answered your question, you can indicate that to the community by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.  That will also earn you some reputation points here on stackoverflow for following the proper procedure.  Reputation points can eventually lead to more privileges on the site.

Answer (score 0):

You are basically doing filtering of records

```
function filterByQuery(query, recipesArray) {
let filterResults = recipesArray;
if (query.name) {
    filterResults = filterResults.filter(recipes => recipes.name === query.name);
}
return filterResults;
```

};

Here recipes are object not string values, so it is returning the objects which have recipes.name equal to query.name.

```
function filterByQuery(query, recipesArray) {
let results;
if (query.name) {
    results = recipesArray.filter(recipes => recipes.name === query.name);
}
return results?.length ? results[0].name : null;
```

};